# Wrap classes in CSS

Tags: css

I want to wrap classes in CSS with a id.

So something like:

```
#main {
    .whatever {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    body {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

I have to wrap a lot of classes and this would be much more easy than write the id in front of every class.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in pure CSS. You may want to use a CSS preprocessor such as [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/#using-less).